# Divide a group of people into two disjoint subgroups (of arbitrary size) and find some values

Tags: algorithm, sorting, max

As we know from programming, sometimes a slight change in a problem can
significantly alter the form of its solution.

Firstly, I want to create a simple algorithm for solving
the following problem and classify it using bigtheta
notation:

**Divide a group of people into two disjoint subgroups
(of arbitrary size) such that the
difference in the total ages of the members of
the two subgroups is as large as possible.**

Now I need to change the problem so that the desired
difference is as small as possible and classify
my approach to the problem.

**Well,first of all I need to create the initial algorithm.
For that, should I make some kind of sorting in order to separate the teams, and how am I suppose to continue?**

**EDIT:** for the first problem,we have ruled out the possibility of a set being an empty set. So all we have to do is just a linear search to find the min age and then put it in a set B. SetA now has all the other ages except the age of setB, which is the min age. So here is the max difference of the total ages of the two sets, as high as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you described the first problem, it is trivial in the way that it requires you to find only the minimum element (in case the subgroups should contain at least 1 member), otherwise it is already solved.

The second problem can be solved recursively the pseudo code would be:

```
// compute sum of all elem of array and store them in sum
min = sum;
globalVec = baseVec;
fun generate(baseVec, generatedVec, position, total)
    if (abs(sum - 2*total) < min){ // check if the distribution is better
        min = abs(sum - 2*total);
        globalVec = generatedVec;
    }
    if (position >= baseVec.length()) return;
    else{
        // either consider elem at position in first group:
        generate(baseVec,generatedVec.pushback(baseVec[position]), position + 1, total+baseVec[position]);
        // or consider elem at position is second group:
        generate(baseVec,generatedVec, position + 1, total);
    }
```

And now just start the function with `generate(baseVec,"",0,0)` where `""` stand for an empty vector.

The algo can be drastically improved by applying it to a sorted array, hence adding a test condition to stop branching, but the idea stays the same.

Comment: for the first problem,we have ruled out the possibility of a set being an empty set. So all we have to do is just a linear search to find the min age and then put it in a set B. SetA now has all the other ages excet the age of setB,which is the min age.So here is the max difference of the total ages of the two sets,as high as possible

@Alexandru

Comment: Yes, that's what I've said.

Comment: so as i understand ,the solution you gave me just calculates the least possible difference in the sum of the ages.. am i right?